# Real-time data in a grid - better method

Tags: jqgrid

What is for you the better approach for displaying real-time data (Stock Exchange, Weather, ...) in a grid ?
I use this method:

```
setInterval(function(){
      jQuery("#list1").trigger('reloadGrid');
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I find your question very interesting. I think the question could be interesting for many other users. So +1 from me.

The usage of `setInterval` seams me the best way in common browser independent case. One should of cause save the result of `setInterval` in a variable to be able to use `clearInterval` to stop it.

One more small improvement would be the usage of `[{current:true}]` (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3808014/315935) for details) as the second parameter of `trigger`:

```js
var $grid = jQuery("#list1"), timer;

timer = setInterval(function () {
    $grid.trigger('reloadGrid', [{current: true}]);
}, 5000);
```

It will save selection during the reloading of grid.

Many new web browsers support now [WebSocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket). So it would be better to use the way in case if the web browser supports it. In the way one can skip unneeded grid reloading in case if the data are not changed on server and prevent permanent pooling of the server.

One more common way seems to me also very interesting. If one would use some kind of timestamp of the last changes of the grid data one could verify whether the data are changed or not. One can either uses [ETag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag) or some general additional method on the server for the purpose.

The current [success](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.3.2/js/grid.base.js#L1778-1791) callback of [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) which fill jqGrid allows you use to implement `beforeProcessing` callback to *modify* the server response, but it's *not allows you to stop jqGrid refreshing* based on `jqXHR.satus` value (it would be `xhr.status` in the current jqGrid code). Small modification of [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.3.2/js/grid.base.js#L1780) of the code of jqGrid would allows you to stop jqGrid refreshing in case of unchanged data on the server. One can either test `textStatus` (`st` in the current code of jqGrid) for `"notmodified"` or test `jqXHR.satus` (`xhr.status` in the current jqGrid code) for [304](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection). It's important that to use the scenario you should use `prmNames: { nd:null }` option and set `ETag` and `Cache-Control: private, max-age=0` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9269567/315935), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3885956/315935) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2960874/315935) for additional information).

**UPDATED**: I tried to create the demo project based on my last suggestions and found out that it's not so easy as I described above. Nevertheless I made it working. The difficulty was because one can't see the 304 code from the server response inside of jQuery.ajax. The reason was the following place in the [XMLHttpRequest specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-send-method)

> For **304 Not Modified** responses that are a result of a user agent
>   generated conditional request the user agent must act as if the server
>   gave a **200 OK** response with the appropriate content. The user agent
>   must allow author request headers to override automatic cache
>   validation (e.g. **If-None-Match** or **If-Modified-Since**), in which case
>   **304 Not Modified** responses must be passed through.

So one sees **200 OK** status inside of `success` handler of `$.ajax` instead **304 Not Modified** from the server response. It seems that `XMLHttpRequest` get back just full response from the cache inclusive all HTTP headers. So I decide to change the analyse of cached data just saving of `ETag` from the last HTTP response as new jqGrid parameter and test the `ETag` of the new response with the saved data.

I seen that you use PHP (which I don't use :-(). Nevertheless I can read and understand PHP code. I hope you can in the same way read C# code and understand the main idea. So you will be able to implement the same in PHP.

Now I describe what I did. First of all I modified [the lines](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.3.2/js/grid.base.js#L1779-1781) of jqGrid source code which use `beforeProcessing` callback from

```js
if ($.isFunction(ts.p.beforeProcessing)) {
    ts.p.beforeProcessing.call(ts, data, st, xhr);
}
```

to

```js
if ($.isFunction(ts.p.beforeProcessing)) {
    if (ts.p.beforeProcessing.call(ts, data, st, xhr) === false) {
        endReq();
        return;
    }
}
```

It will allows to return false from `beforeProcessing` to skip refreshing of data - to skip processing of data. The implementation of `beforeProcessing` which I used in the demo are based on the usage `ETag`:

```js
beforeProcessing: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
    var currentETag = jqXHR.getResponseHeader("ETag"), $this = $(this),
        eTagOfGridData = $this.jqGrid('getGridParam', "eTagOfGridData");
    if (currentETag === eTagOfGridData) {
        $("#isProcessed").text("Processing skipped!!!");
        return false;
    }
    $this.jqGrid('setGridParam', { eTagOfGridData: currentETag });
    $("#isProcessed").text("Processed");
}
```

The line `$("#isProcessed").text("Processed");` or the line `$("#isProcessed").text("Processing skipped!!!");` set `"Processed"` or `"Processing skipped!!!"` text in the div which I used to indicate visually that the data from the server was used to fill the grid.

In the demo *I display two grids with the same data*. The fist grid I use for editing of data. The second grid pulls the data from the server every second. If the data are not changed on the server the HTTP traffic looks as following

HTTP Request:

```
GET http://localhost:34336/Home/DynamicGridData?search=false&rows=10&page=1&sidx=Id&sord=desc&filters= HTTP/1.1
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Referer: http://localhost:34336/
Accept-Language: de-DE
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; LEN2)
Host: localhost:34336
If-None-Match: D5k+rkf3T7SDQl8b4/Y1aQ==
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

HTTP Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Server: ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
Date: Sun, 06 May 2012 19:44:36 GMT
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 2.0
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
ETag: D5k+rkf3T7SDQl8b4/Y1aQ==
Connection: Close
```

So **no data will be transferred from the server** if the data are not changed. If the data are changed, the HTTP header will be started with `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` and contains `ETag` of new modified data together with the page of data itself.

One can refresh the data of the grid either manually using "Refresh" button of the navigator or uses "Start Autorefresh" button which will execute `$grid1.trigger('reloadGrid', [{ current: true}]);` every second. The page looks like

[image]

I marked the most important parts on the bottom of the page with the color boxes. If one `loadui: "disable"` option then one don't see any changes on the grid at all during the pulling of the server. If one commented the option that one will see "Loading..." div for very short time, but **no grid contain will flicker**.

After starting of "Autorefreshing" one will see mostly the picture like below

[image]

If one would change some row in the first grid, the second grid will be changed in a second and one will see `"Processed"` text which will be changed to `"Processing skipped!!!"` text in one more second.

The corresponding code (I used ASP.NET MVC) on the server side is mostly the following

```cs
public JsonResult DynamicGridData(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows,
                                  bool search, string filters)
{
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability (HttpCacheability.ServerAndPrivate);
    Response.Cache.SetMaxAge (new TimeSpan (0));

    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    ... - do all the work and fill object var result with the data

    // calculate MD5 from the returned data and use it as ETag
    var str = serializer.Serialize (result);
    byte[] inputBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str);
    byte[] hash = MD5.Create().ComputeHash(inputBytes);
    string newETag = Convert.ToBase64String (hash);
    Response.Cache.SetETag (newETag);
    // compare ETag of the data which already has the client with ETag of response
    string incomingEtag = Request.Headers["If-None-Match"];
    if (String.Compare (incomingEtag, newETag, StringComparison.Ordinal) == 0) {
        // we don't need return the data which the client already have
        Response.SuppressContent = true;
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotModified;
        return null;
    }

    return Json (result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I hope that the main idea of the code will be clear also for people which use not only ASP.NET MVC.

**You can download the project [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jqGridAutorefresh.zip).**

**UPDATED**: I posted [the feature request](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/allow-beforeprocessing-to-return-false-for-skipping-processing-of-the-server-response/#p26517) to allow `beforeProcessing` to break processing of the server response by returning `false` value. The corresponding changes are already included (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/1d26922bddabff65f17f0807511a3adb6ca85b7b)) in the main jqGrid code. So the next release of jqGrid will include it.

Comment: Instead of reload the grid every x seconds, is it not possible to "write" directly in the rows ?

Comment: @Bertaud: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. In any way I suppose that you always use `gridview: true` option of jqGrid. It follows that the whole grid body will be updated using one operation, by setting `innerHTML` to the table body. If you would modify many rows or even cells of jqGrid *separately* it could be many time slowly as the reloading of the whole grid. Moreover if some rows are added or removed the pager have to be modified too. So reloading of the grid seems me the best way.

Comment: @Bertaud: You should understand the changing of *one* element on the page follow to recalculation of position of **all** other existing elements on the page (reflow). So reducing the number of changes of the page could be the most important for improving performance of the page. See [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/reflow) for example more about minimizing browser reflow.

Comment: I am using current:true but not in the trigger. I mean by writing in the rows the use of jQuery("#list1").updateGridRows(s,"id"); with s = array. That could improve the refresh ?

Comment: @Bertaud: The method `updateGridRows` is no more part of jqGrid. It's  not supported starting with version 4.0 of jqGrid (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:upgrade_from_3.8_to_4.0.0#the_following_methods_are_no_more_supported)). You can find it still in `grid.addons.js`, but the method is not quickly. It uses sequential `jQuery.html` to update every cell of rows from `s` (`$("#list1").updateGridRows(s);`). I would not recommend you to use the method.

Comment: Thank you for your advices. That means I cannot do better.

Comment: I found this: www.lightstreamer.com/demo/jqgriddemo/

Comment: @Bertaud: I found only http://www.lightstreamer.com/demo/jqGridDemo/. The URL http://www.lightstreamer.com/demo/jqgriddemo/ shows 404 error: "Sorry, but the page you are trying to view does not exist.". The demo uses very old jqGrid 3.5.3 and uses `setRowData` to update the data. Depend on the number of data which will be updated the way could be very good or very bad. The most important part or the demo is inside of `lightstreamer.js`. It sent POST request every 0.2-0.3 sec and get the changed data back. In general it's interesting, but is uses lightstreamer solution, so it's not common way.

Comment: @Bertaud: I implemented my suggestion to use ETag and modified version of `beforeProcessing` to optimize reloading of the grid in case of unchanged data on the server. See **UPDATED** part of my answer. I hope it will be helpful either for you or for another jqGrid user having the same problem.

Comment: @Bertaud: You are welcome! It's just so that I have to think about some problem like yours. So I have to write the demo, at least for myself. :-) I posted my suggestion as [the feature request](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/allow-beforeprocessing-to-return-false-for-skipping-processing-of-the-server-response/#p26517).

Comment: @Bertaud: My feature request is now included in the main code of jqGrid (see "UPDATED" part of the answer)

Comment: @Oleg Will `$grid.trigger('reloadGrid', [{current: true}])` reload the complete grid, even if there was a change only in the single column of the database table? Or will it reload only the row that changed?

Comment: @SuhailGupta: `$grid.trigger('reloadGrid', [{current: true}])` reloads **the whole grid body**. The problem is only what do the code exactly, which `datatype` have the grid, the page size of the grid and many other parts of your exact scenario. The answer is very old and jqGrid have many new features now. In any way if you are sure that only one row is changed and you get the data of the row one can use `setRowData` method. On the other side the changing of one row of the grid can follow changing position of *other row and other HTML elements on the page*. So web browser reflow will be done.

Comment: @SuhailGupta: [Reflow](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/reflow) can be expensive. Chening of the whole grid body will be done as *one operation* in jqGrid: assigning `innerHTML` to `<tbody>`. So the time *on the client side* for changing of one row and the time of changing the whole grid body could be not so different. I have to repeat that the best solution depend on the exact scenario in your application.

Comment: @Oleg The application will work on intranet. The data is constantly written on to the database, but some values could become constant with time.

Comment: @SuhailGupta: Sorry, but there are no "the best way" to implement dynamical update of the grid based on changing of data on the server. I wrote you that one have to know a lot of details. The posted answer just shows the main case: one can load the data of the grid very quickly (from intranet which quick database access for example). The code shows how to implement simplest pooling the data with combination with **skipping reloading if no changing take place since the latest loading of the grid**. One can reload the whole grid on changing if it's quickly enough (small page size of the grid).